# jQuery get today currency rate from ECB XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I need to get today rate for `CZK` currency from European Central Bank XML -> http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml

This is my code now

```
var xml = $.parseXML("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml"),
$xml = $( xml ),
$test = $xml.find('Cube');

console.log($test.text());
```

and I got an error `Uncaught Error: Invalid XML`

Comment: Get the XML file and try to validate it.  It may not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the [parseXml](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) function of JQuery is a string containing the XML document.

So in your example it tries to parse the URL string as XML which apparently fails.
To parse the data from the URL load it yourself and then put it into the `parseXml` function.

Comment: But when I tried to do `$.get( "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist-90d.xml", function({ alert( "success" ); })` I got this error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: @Kicker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource